# Error running mlflow project with MLproject file

Tags: python, anaconda, mlflow

I'm learning mlflow currently notably with there tutorial (https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tutorials-and-examples/tutorial.html). I'm trying to run a project directly, which requires the .py file, MLproject file and environment -yml file. I have all this from their tutorial example in the file `sklearn_elasticnet_wine`.

Here is the python file:

```
# The data set used in this example is from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality
# P. Cortez, A. Cerdeira, F. Almeida, T. Matos and J. Reis.
# Modeling wine preferences by data mining from physicochemical properties. In Decision Support Systems, Elsevier, 47(4):547-553, 2009.

import os
import warnings
import sys

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import mlflow
from mlflow.models import infer_signature
import mlflow.sklearn

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def eval_metrics(actual, pred):
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual, pred))
    mae = mean_absolute_error(actual, pred)
    r2 = r2_score(actual, pred)
    return rmse, mae, r2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    np.random.seed(40)

    # Read the wine-quality csv file from the URL
    csv_url = (
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlflow/mlflow/master/tests/datasets/winequality-red.csv"
    )
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(csv_url, sep=";")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(
            "Unable to download training & test CSV, check your internet connection. Error: %s", e
        )

    # Split the data into training and test sets. (0.75, 0.25) split.
    train, test = train_test_split(data)

    # The predicted column is "quality" which is a scalar from [3, 9]
    train_x = train.drop(["quality"], axis=1)
    test_x = test.drop(["quality"], axis=1)
    train_y = train[["quality"]]
    test_y = test[["quality"]]

    alpha = float(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 0.5
    l1_ratio = float(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 0.5

    with mlflow.start_run():
        lr = ElasticNet(alpha=alpha, l1_ratio=l1_ratio, random_state=42)
        lr.fit(train_x, train_y)

        predicted_qualities = lr.predict(test_x)

        (rmse, mae, r2) = eval_metrics(test_y, predicted_qualities)

        print("Elasticnet model (alpha={:f}, l1_ratio={:f}):".format(alpha, l1_ratio))
        print("  RMSE: %s" % rmse)
        print("  MAE: %s" % mae)
        print("  R2: %s" % r2)

        mlflow.log_param("alpha", alpha)
        mlflow.log_param("l1_ratio", l1_ratio)
        mlflow.log_metric("rmse", rmse)
        mlflow.log_metric("r2", r2)
        mlflow.log_metric("mae", mae)

        predictions = lr.predict(train_x)
        signature = infer_signature(train_x, predictions)

        tracking_url_type_store = urlparse(mlflow.get_tracking_uri()).scheme

        # Model registry does not work with file store
        if tracking_url_type_store != "file":
            # Register the model
            # There are other ways to use the Model Registry, which depends on the use case,
            # please refer to the doc for more information:
            # https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/model-registry.html#api-workflow
            mlflow.sklearn.log_model(
                lr, "model", registered_model_name="ElasticnetWineModel", signature=signature
            )
        else:
            mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model", signature=signature)
```

Here is the MLproject file:

```
name: tutorial

python_env: python_env.yaml

entry_points:
  main:
    parameters:
      alpha: {type: float, default: 0.5}
      l1_ratio: {type: float, default: 0.1}
    command: "python train.py {alpha} {l1_ratio}"
```

and here is the .yml file:

```
name: tutorial
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pip
  - pip:
      - scikit-learn==1.2.0
      - mlflow>=1.0
      - pandas
```

I run the following command to run the project:

```
(PyTEST) C:\Users\antdu953\Desktop\mlflow\examples>mlflow run sklearn_elasticnet_wine -P alpha=0.42
```

and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\Scripts\mlflow.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\cli.py", line 204, in run
    projects.run(
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\__init__.py", line 338, in run
    submitted_run_obj = _run(
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\__init__.py", line 105, in _run
    submitted_run = backend.run(
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\backend\local.py", line 163, in run
    python_bin_path = _install_python(python_env.python, pyenv_root=pyenv_root)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\virtualenv.py", line 126, in _install_python
    else _find_latest_installable_python_version(version)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\virtualenv.py", line 102, in _find_latest_installable_python_version
    lines = _exec_cmd(
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\process.py", line 95, in _exec_cmd
    process = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\subprocess.py", line 1456, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

To fix it I move to the repertory containing the file `C:\Users\antdu953\Desktop\mlflow\examples\sklearn_elasticnet_wine` and run again:

```
(PyTEST) C:\Users\antdu953\Desktop\mlflow\examples\sklearn_elasticnet_wine>mlflow run sklearn_elasticnet_wine -P alpha=0.42
```

As a result I have an error (see below) that seems to complain about access to git repertory even though I'm trying to run locally ?
I haven't find anything in the tutorial itself, I just run the command provided..

```
2023/07/13 13:51:04 INFO mlflow.projects.utils: === Fetching project from sklearn_elasticnet_wine into C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpeeqgfmp9 ===
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\Scripts\mlflow.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\cli.py", line 204, in run
    projects.run(
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\__init__.py", line 338, in run
    submitted_run_obj = _run(
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\__init__.py", line 105, in _run
    submitted_run = backend.run(
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\backend\local.py", line 83, in run
    work_dir = fetch_and_validate_project(project_uri, version, entry_point, params)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\utils.py", line 137, in fetch_and_validate_project
    work_dir = _fetch_project(uri=uri, version=version)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\utils.py", line 171, in _fetch_project
    _fetch_git_repo(parsed_uri, version, dst_dir)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\utils.py", line 221, in _fetch_git_repo
    output = g.execute(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\PyTEST\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 1109, in execute
    raise GitCommandError(redacted_command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git remote show origin
  stderr: 'fatal: 'sklearn_elasticnet_wine' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have `mlflow, version 2.4.2`

Anyone has an idea ?